# zalando problem-spring-web generates unwanted stack trace

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson-modules

I'm trying to implement RFC 7807 in my Spring Boot project using zalando problem-spring-web https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web

I've done the setup according to this guide https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web/tree/master/problem-spring-web

When an exception is thrown, the `Problem` instance does get generated, but its serialized JSON form is not as expected, most notably the stack trace is included when it shouldn't.

After some debugging, it seems that the `ProblemModule` is not registered in the `ObjectMapper` that is used to serialize the problem (its `setupModule` method is never called). I was under the impression that declaring a bean of type `Module` was enough to have it picked up by Spring and registered in the `ObjectMapper`, but it doesn't happen here.

The doc says

> In case you want to enable stack traces, please configure your
>   ProblemModule as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
     .registerModule(new ProblemModule().withStackTraces());
```

which seems to imply that you need to instantiate your own `ObjectMapper`, but then how to make sure that it's used by the library when deserializing the Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I can't get the `ObjectMapper` to register my `Module`s I figured I had to do it myself so I came up with this solution that seems to work:

```
@Configuration
public class ProblemConfiguration implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        objectMapper.registerModules(
                new ProblemModule(),
                new ConstraintViolationProblemModule()
        );
    }
}
```

If someone has an idea why it's not working as expected, I'd be glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring boot 1.1.0, the JacksonAutoConfiguration creates an ObjectMapper bean and automatically registers all module found in your registered beans,

so you juste need to create does two beans modules and use de already configured ObjectMapper like this:

```
 /*
 * Module for serialization/deserialization of RFC7807 Problem.
 */
@Bean
public ProblemModule problemModule() {
    return new ProblemModule();
}

/*
 * Module for serialization/deserialization of ConstraintViolationProblem.
 */
@Bean
public ConstraintViolationProblemModule constraintViolationProblemModule() {
    return new ConstraintViolationProblemModule();
}
```

use configured ObjectMapper for ex in service Classe

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper
```